# Why Ad Unit IDs for Interstitial Ads not Stored in strings.xml?

Tags: android, xml, admob, ads, interstitial

I'm new to AdMob and Android in general, but I was reading through the tutorials for adding Interstitial Ads. Based on their examples, they store the Ad Unit Ids for Banner Ads in the strings.xml file, but they hard-code the Ad Unit Ids for interstitial ads. It seems it would be best to store all Ad Unit Ids in one file, rather than having them hard-coded sometimes. What's the reason for this?

Answer (score 0):

That means that the interstitial ads are initialized and the values are set for it not in the layout file, but in the related Java file. It is added like normal but the setup is different.

It is not related to strings.xml, but the layout xml file

No idea why you involved strings.xml when it clearly states: "defined in an XML layout file,"

Comment: I guess what I'm asking is whether it is common practice to hard-code the Ad Unit ID into the `mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId(mAdunitId);` line and why it wouldn't be better to store that Ad Id in the strings.xml file so that all ad Ids are in the same location for ease of access later?

Comment: Don't hardcode! The statement in your question is related to how you initialize the view in the XML file. Use strings.xml for the ad unit ID no matter what! They never stated you not to during the interstitial ads documentation